# Python pandas: Add a column to my dataframe that counts a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a dataframe 'gt' like this:

```
org     group
org1      1
org2      1
org3      2
org4      3
org5      3
org6      3
```

and I would like to add column 'count' to gt dataframe to counts number member of the groups, expected results like this:

```
org     group   count
org1      1       2
org2      1       2
org3      2       1
org4      3       3
org5      3       3
org6      3       3
```

I know how to do it per one item of the group, but do not know how to make the count repeated for all of the group items, here is the code I have used:

```py
gtcounts = gt.groupby('group').count()
```

Comment: This question includes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/create-column-of-value-counts-in-pandas-dataframe) one. The other link has more responses and therefore might be also helpful for those who landed here.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) this will return a Series aligned with the original df:

```
In [223]:

df['count'] = df.groupby('group')['group'].transform('count')
df
Out[223]:
    org  group  count
0  org1      1      2
1  org2      1      2
2  org3      2      1
3  org4      3      3
4  org5      3      3
5  org6      3      3
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get the same result with apply() or map()?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/create-column-of-value-counts-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done with a combination of `value_counts()` and `map` as well. Basically, the idea is to find the counts of each group; then map these counts back to the groups.

```py
df['count'] = df['group'].map(df['group'].value_counts())

# or
df['count'] = df['group'].map(df.groupby('group')['group'].count())
```

Also `groupby.transform` can be used with `size()` as well.

```py
df['count'] = df.groupby('group').transform('size')
```

Both of these methods produce the following transformation.

[image: result1]

If you arrived here looking for a way to assign the per-group counter as a column, then use `groupby.cumcount()`.

```py
df['count'] = df.groupby('group').cumcount()+1
```

[image: result2]