# Is there a way to count the values?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to count the total from NAME, B, C, D columns like so.

| NAME | B | C | D | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dorj | jan | hr | nd | 11 |
| tash | feb | mkt | nd | 12 |
| dorj | jan | fin | yy | 19 |

Column "Count" counts the values.

| NAME | B | C | D | TOTAL | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dorj | jan | hr | nd | 11 | 2 |
| dorj | jan | fin | yy | 19 | 2 |
| tash | feb | mkt | kk | 12 | 1 |

Comment: [groupby count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) -> `ed = df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False)['B'].count()` or  if you want counts of distinct `NAME` `B` groups groupby multiple columns -> `ed = df.groupby(['NAME', 'B'], as_index=False)['B'].count()`

Comment: thank you, I wanted to add count column in the dataframe.

Comment: [transform count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29791952/15497888) -> `df['COUNT'] = df.groupby('NAME')['B'].transform('count')` or `df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['NAME', 'B'])['B'].transform('count')`. It's still unclear whether we're grouping by `NAME` and `B` or just `NAME`