# Add column of value_counts based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

So basically this questios in equal to either [17709270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/create-column-of-value-counts-in-pandas-dataframe) or [29791785](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791785/python-pandas-add-a-column-to-my-dataframe-that-counts-a-variable), with the difference that I want to count values based on multiple columns instead of just one.

I have for example

```
    column1 column2 column3 column4 
1   a       2       True    asdmn
2   b       2       False   asdd
3   c       3       False   asddas
4   a       2       False   grtgv
5   b       1       False   bdfbf
```

and my result should be

```
    column1 column2 column3 column4  counts
1   a       2       True    asdmn    2
2   b       2       False   asdd     1
3   a       3       False   asddas   1
4   a       2       False   grtgv    2
5   b       1       False   bdfbf    1
```

If I am not mistaken none of the respones of previous referenced questions work for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])['column1'].transform('size')
```

Answer (score 1):

With `value_counts`, you could do:

```
cols = ["column1", "column2"]
df = df.assign(counts=df.set_index(cols).index.map(df[cols].value_counts()))

print(df)

  column1  column2  column3 column4 counts
1       a        2     True   asdmn      2
2       b        2    False    asdd      1
3       c        3    False  asddas      1
4       a        2    False   grtgv      2
5       b        1    False   bdfbf      1
```

Answer (score 0):

So first was to do a value count on several columns for what responses in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589829/how-to-get-value-counts-for-multiple-columns-at-once-in-pandas-dataframe) were useful. Basically I tried two options that worked for me:

`counts = df.value_counts(['column1', 'column2']).reset_index(name='counts')`

Then I used `merged` as in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#merging-on-a-combination-of-columns-and-index-levels):

```
counts = df.value_counts(['column1', 'column2']).reset_index(name='counts')
duplicated_sats.merge(counts, on=['column1', 'column2'])
```