# Create a pandas dataframe of counts

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a pandas dataframe with two columns, the first being the unique values of one of my columns and the second being the count of unique values.

I have seen many posts (such [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/i-want-to-create-a-column-of-value-counts-in-my-pandas-dataframe)) as  that describe how to get the counts, but the issue I'm running into is when I try to create a dataframe the column values become my index.

Sample data: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Red', 'Red', 'Blue'], 'State': ['MA', 'PA', 'PA']})`. I want to end up with a dataframe like:

```
   Color Count
0   Red  2
1  Blue  1
```

I have tried the following, but in all cases the index ends up as Color and the Count is the only column in the dataframe.

Attempt 1:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df['Color'].value_counts())
# And resetting the index just gets rid of Color, which I want to keep
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Attempt 2:

```
df3 = df['Color'].value_counts()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=df3, index=range(df3.shape[0]))
```

Attempt 3:

```
df4 = df.groupby('Color')
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4['Color'].count())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way to do this, using `value_counts`:

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Red', 'Red', 'Blue'], 'State': ['MA', 'PA', 'PA']})

In [11]: df.Color.value_counts().reset_index().rename(
           columns={'index': 'Color', 0: 'count'})
Out[11]:
  Color  count
0   Red      2
1  Blue      1
```

Answer (score 3):

One readable solution is to use [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) methods:

```
res = df['Color'].value_counts()\
                 .to_frame('count').rename_axis('Color')\
                 .reset_index()

print(res)

  Color  count
0   Red      2
1  Blue      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially equivalent to setting the column names, but using the rename method instead:

```
df.groupby('Color').count().reset_index().rename(columns={'State': 'Count'})
```

Comment: I noticed a small issue with this approach: if there are more than two columns, then all additional columns will get the counts as well.

Comment: It depends what you want to see. Say there are two rows with colour=red, then for each column there are two values for which the row's colour=red. You could always explicitly select one column only.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.groupby('Color').count().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Color','Count']
```