# Create a column of counts in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a column of counts in a pandas dataframe. Here is the input:

```
dict = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'cat': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 'status': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]}

  id cat status
0 1  A   1
1 2  A   1
2 3  A   1
3 4  A   1
4 5  A   2
5 6  B   1
```

Preferred output:

```
  id cat status status_1_for_cat_count status_2_for_category_count
0 1  A   1      4                      1
1 2  A   1      4                      1
2 3  A   1      4                      1
3 4  A   1      4                      1
4 5  A   2      4                      1
5 6  B   1      1                      0
```

As can hopefully be seen, I'm trying to get the full counts added for each row to two columns (one for each status). I have tried several approaches, mostly with groupby in combination with unique_counts, transform, apply, filter, merges and what not, but have not been able to get this to work. I am able to do this on a single column easily ([I want to create a column of value_counts in my pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/i-want-to-create-a-column-of-value-counts-in-my-pandas-dataframe)), but not with two different statuses combined with the category.

Comment: Status is different in dict and the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, use `pd.crosstab` to create a two way table with `cat` as index, then join back with the original data frame on `cat` column:

```
df.join(pd.crosstab(df.cat, 'status_' + df.status.astype(str)), on='cat')

#  cat  id  status  status_1  status_2
#0   A   1       1         4         1
#1   A   2       1         4         1
#2   A   3       1         4         1
#3   A   4       1         4         1
#4   A   5       2         4         1
#5   B   6       1         1         0
```

Comment: I certainly didn't think about crosstab

Comment: @Dark It's a little convenient function I use quite often. I like the use of `get_dummies` here.

Comment: This worked great! Was very quick and resource friendly. I had never thought to use crosstab. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `get_dummies` first then `groupby` transform i.e

```
one = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['id','cat']).astype(str))
two = one.groupby(['cat']).transform('sum').reset_index()

   id cat  status_1  status_2
0   1   A         4         1
1   2   A         4         1
2   3   A         4         1
3   4   A         4         1
4   5   A         4         1
5   6   B         1         0
```

Comment: You can compress this a bit: `pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('cat').status).add_prefix('status_').groupby(level=0).transform('sum')`

Comment: Hey @Dark, this answer worked well on the sample DataFrame but caused a Memory Error on the full DataFrame (its a rather large dataset with many categories and in that case get_dummies uses a fair amount of memory; it used about 6GB before it crashed). It was also more CPU intense. I didn't have those two issues with Psidom crosstab answer. It's possible that this answer works better for other use cases though. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @MathijsdeJong you know get_dummies was supposed to be faster, I never got into memory error till today. Glad you got it done. And if the answer was useful upvote and support :)

Comment: adding a new way for using get_dummies :-)