# Using Groupby to store value_counts in new column in Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I've used to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709453/4539956) to compute and store value_counts of a column in Pandas and store the results in a new column.

Now I'm trying to do the same for a Dask Dataframe, but it causes the following error:

```py
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform('count', meta='int').compute()
```

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

P.S. The `df` dataframe has four partitions.

How can I count the value_count of column `A` and store them in the `new_column` in Dask, as same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709453/4539956)?

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't need to stick with `transform` (which was introduced in the most recent dask version see [issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5327)) I suggest you to use a left merge as in the following code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,0,1,1,1,2,2],
                   "B":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

out = df.groupby("A")["B"]\
        .count()\
        .compute()\
        .reset_index(name="new_column")

df = dd.merge(df, out, on=["A"], how="left")
```