# Counts for unique values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to find counts for unique values. Goal is to have df having `df.a.value_counts().unique()` in one column and in next column their counts.

```
df.a.value_counts().unique()
```

.

```
 array([94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80, 79, 78,
           77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61,
           60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44,
           43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27,
           26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,
            9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4])
```

.

```
df.groupby('a').size()
```

.

```
    5faac7     94
    5faacc     94
    5faadc     92
    5faaesc    94
    5faaxsc    94
        ..
    e105ba9    94
    25ded 0    55
    7d25de     65
    17d25d9    42
    ba98dd8    10
```

.

```
uniques_size_counts= pd.DataFrame(       , columns=["Size", "counts"])
```

**Goal**

```
size  counts 
94    67
93    45
.....
```

Comment: You mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709453/8881141)?

Comment: @Mr.T No it is different,  `df.a.value_counts().value_counts()` solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) once more:

```
df.a.value_counts().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `value_counts()` and then create a new DataFrame.

```
new_df = df.a.value_counts()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```

Comment: I already tried this and did not work , only `df.a.value_counts().value_counts()` worked