# python Count Column

Tags: python, pandas, count, mergeddictionaries

I'm trying to create new column with the count of each attribute (Number) but it's given me the total count of row as shown below

```
POM = pd.read_excel('POM.xlsx' , sheet_name='Sheet1')
POM['Merged']=POM['ACD ID'].astype(str)+PG['Date'].astype(str)
POM['Count']=POM['Merged'].count()
print(POM.head(2))
POM.to_excel('Test.xlsx' , index=False)
```

Result

```
        Date  ACD ID           Merged  Count
0 2022-03-08   14004  140042022-03-08    986
1 2022-03-09   14004  140042022-03-09    986
```

How can I count the unique code which is repetition found in column (Merged)?

```
# Date              ACD ID     Merged     Count
2022-03-08 00:00:00 14004   140042022-03-08 10
2022-03-09 00:00:00 14004   140042022-03-09 49
2022-03-10 00:00:00 14004   140042022-03-10 62
```

i have try the bellow code as answered & i found accurate answer but in same time the Merged New coulmn that i created by group(date+ ACD ID) are not accuaret as shown below , that date in ( merged ) not matched the date

```
POM = pd.read_excel('POM.xlsx' , sheet_name='Sheet1')
POM['Merged']=POM['ACD ID'].astype(str)+PG['Date'].astype(str)
#POM['Count'] = POM['Merged'].count()
POM['Count'] = POM['Merged'].copy().replace(POM['Merged'].value_counts().to_dict())
#POM['Count']=POM.groupby(["Merged"])["Merged"].transform("count")
#POM['counts'] = POM['Merged'].map(POM['Merged'].value_counts())

print(POM.head(6))
#POM.to_excel('Test.xlsx' , index=False)
```

result

```
        Date  ACD ID           Merged  Count
0 2022-03-08   14004  140042022-03-08      1
1 2022-03-08   14005  140052022-03-09      1
2 2022-03-08   14006  140062022-03-10      1
3 2022-03-08   14007  140072022-03-15      1
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your input df with expected output.

Comment: input is $date { 2022-03-08,2022-03-09,2022-03-10} and $ User {1411,1411,1411} as i merged both to get unique value as i have rep in data as agent can do many action in one day . i need to get the count of rep data

Comment: In my sample the merging happened between two columns in the same DataFrame, in yours you use `POM` and `PG`. Are these two DataFrames with the same number of rows and both in the right (and same) order?

Comment: ohh sorry i didn't notice , problem solved now , many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby()` and then `transform("count")`:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({"date": ["2022", "2023", "2023", "2024"],
                       "id": ["a", "a", "a", "c"]})
df["merged"] = df["date"] + "_" + df["id"]
print(df)
>    date id  merged
  0  2022  a  2022_a
  1  2023  a  2023_a
  2  2023  a  2023_a
  3  2024  c  2024_c

df["counts"] = df.groupby(["merged"])["merged"].transform("count")
print(df)
>    date id  merged  counts
  0  2022  a  2022_a       1
  1  2023  a  2023_a       2
  2  2023  a  2023_a       2
  3  2024  c  2024_c       1
```

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709270/create-column-of-value-counts-in-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: as count is working fine i guess it's counting as Merged column but as below answer too the Merged column is modifying the date by it self as it keep adding date + 1 in the merged new column while in date it's the same

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```py
df['Count'] = df['Merged'].copy().replace(df['Merged'].value_counts().to_dict())
```

You create a copy of Merged, then count the values in Merged and convert it to a dict of {id: count}, then use that dictionary to replace the id values in the copied Merged column.

This has the added benefit over `groupby` that you can retain your original indexing and shape of the dataframe while still filling in the counts of each id.

Ex:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022", "2023", "2023", "2024"],
                       "id": ["a", "a", "a", "c"]})
df["merged"] = df["date"] + "_" + df["id"]
df['Count'] = df['merged'].copy().replace(df['merged'].value_counts().to_dict())

   date id  merged  Count
0  2022  a  2022_a      1
1  2023  a  2023_a      2
2  2023  a  2023_a      2
3  2024  c  2024_c      1
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the comment , i tried that & i guess the count code working fine , but i have found that ( Merged ) is not accurate as it keep changing the date from it self while no change in the source                                                                                                 Date  ACD ID           Merged  Count
0 2022-03-08   14004  140042022-03-08      1
1 2022-03-08   14004  140042022-03-09      1
2 2022-03-08   14004  140042022-03-10      1
3 2022-03-08   14004  140042022-03-15      1